# Are there guidelines on how many parameters a function should accept?

Tags: functions, parameters

I've noticed a few functions I work with have 6 or more parameters, whereas in most libraries I use it is rare to find a function that takes more than 3.

Often a lot of these extra parameters are binary options to alter the function behaviour. I think that some of these umpteen-parametered functions should probably be refactored. Is there a guideline for what number is too many?

Comment: A lot of people here saying that this isn't really the way to go with a on of parms. However what about object constructors. Taken an ORM with a class and its INIT method. I have had cases where i would need 10 or more params that have to be set to something that can't default well. I hate looking at the init  function because its hard to work with and hard to remember. Is a constructor an OK edge case or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @Ominus: The idea is that you want to keep your classes focused. Focused classes usually do not have as many dependencies/attributes therefore you'd have less parameters to the constructor. Some buzz word people throw in at this point is *high cohesion* and *single responsibility principle*. If you feel that these are not violated and still need lots of params, consider using the Builder pattern.

Comment: Definitely don't follow the example of [MPI_Sendrecv()](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Sendrecv.html), which takes 12 parameters!

Comment: I updated my answer with more details about the guidelines.

Comment: A non negative amount. If the amount is too big for comfort, consider using complex parameters, object fields/properties, optional parameters, overloads.

Comment: @Ominus you should ask that in a question, not a comment. Also the answer is no.

Comment: The project I'm currently working on uses a certain framework, in which methods with 10+ parameters is commonplace. I'm calling one particular method with 27 parameters in a couple of places. Every time I see it I die a little inside.

Comment: Never add boolean switches to alter function behavior. Split the function instead. Break out the common behavior into new functions.

Comment: Yes, there are guidelines. One of the guidelines says at most three parameters. Another guideline says up to five. Another guideline says use 0 and use global variables to transfer data around. Another guideline says as many as necessary and definitely don't do what the previous guideline said.

Comment: One practical consideration when designing your API is Java is limited to 255 parameters (minus one for every long or double typed parameter). I try to stay under 200 just to be safe.

Comment: @Ominus What? Only 10 parameters? That's nothing, [much more is needed](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1509). :D

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there are [very legitimate libraries with 25-parameter constructors](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d). In this case, it's actually quite necessary!

Comment: Samurai Jack proved that there is NEVER any need for more than four parameters, except for certain meta-programs, like compilers.

Comment: Alan Perlis once said that if you have written a function with 10 parameters, you have probably missed one.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

I've never seen a guideline, but in my experience a function that takes more than three or four parameters indicates one of two problems:

1. The function is doing too much. It should be split into several smaller functions, each which have a smaller parameter set.
2. There is another object hiding in there. You may need to create another object or data structure that includes these parameters. See this article on the [Parameter Object](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object) pattern for more information.

It's difficult to tell what you're looking at without more information. Chances are the refactoring you need to do is split the function into smaller functions which are called from the parent depending on those flags that are currently being passed to the function.

There are some good gains to be had by doing this:

- It makes your code easier to read. I personally find it much easier to read a "rules list" made up of an `if` structure that calls a lot of methods with descriptive names than a structure that does it all in one method.
- It's more unit testable. You've split your problem into several smaller tasks that are individually very simple. The unit test collection would then be made up of a behavioral test suite that checks the paths through the master method and a collection of smaller tests for each individual procedure.

Comment: Parameter abstraction has been turned into a design pattern? What happens if you have 3 parameter classes. Do you add 9 more method overloads to handle the different possible combinations of parameters? That sounds like a nasty O(n^2) parameter declaration issue. Oh wait, you can only inherit 1 class in Java/C# so that will require some more biolerplate (maybe some more subclassing) to make it work in practice. Sorry, I'm not convinced. Ignoring the more expressive approaches a language may offer in favor of complexity just feels wrong.

Comment: Unless you use the Pattern Object pattern to package variables in an object instance and pass that in as a parameter. That works for packaging but it may be tempting to create classes of dissimilar variables just for the convenience of simplifying the method definition.

Comment: @EvanPlaice I'm not saying that you have to use that pattern whenever you have more than one parameter - you're absolutely correct that that becomes even nastier than the first list. There may be cases where you really do need a large number of parameters and it just doesn't work to wrap them up in an object. I've yet to meet a case in enterprise development that did not fall into one of the two buckets I mentioned in my answer - that's not saying one doesn't exist though.

Comment: @MichaelK If you have never used them, try googling 'object initializers'. It's a pretty novel approach that significantly reduces definition boilerplate. In theory, you could eliminate a classes constructors, parameters, and overloads all in one shot. In practice though, it's usually good to maintain one common constructor and rely on the 'object initializer' syntax for the rest of the obscure/niche properties. IMHO, it's the closest you get to the expressiveness of dynamically typed languages in a statically typed language.

Comment: @Evain Plaice: Since when are dynamically typed languages expressive?

Comment: God functions are just as big a problem as god objects.

Comment: Although each individual function would take 1-4 parameters after refactoring a large function, still the parent function has to provide all of the paramaeters, and thus itself having many parameters anyway. Where does this chain stop? ```main()```?

Answer (score 54):

According to "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship", zero is the ideal, one or two are acceptable, three in special cases and four or more, never!

The words of the author:

> The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero (niladic). Next comes one (monadic), followed closely by two (dyadic). Three arguments (triadic) should be avoided where possible. More than three (polyadic) requires very special justification—and then shouldn’t be used anyway.

In this book there is a chapter talking only about functions where parameters are large discussed, so I think this book can be a good guideline of how much parameters you need.

In my personal opinion, one parameter is better than no one because I think is more clear what is going on.

As example, in my opinion the second choice is better because is more clear what the method is processing:

```
LangDetector detector = new LangDetector(someText);
//lots of lines
String language = detector.detectLanguage();
```

vs.

```
LangDetector detector = new LangDetector();
//lots of lines
String language = detector.detectLanguage(someText);
```

About a lot of parameters, this can be a sign that some variables can be grouped into a single object or, in this case, a lot of booleans can represent that the function/method is doing more that one thing, and in this case, is better refactoring each one of these behavior in a different function.

Comment: "three in special cases and four or more, never!" BS. How about Matrix.Create(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9); ?

Comment: Zero is ideal? How the heck do functions get information? Global/instance/static/whatever variables? YUCK.

Comment: That's a bad example. The answer is obviously: `String language = detectLanguage(someText);`. In either of your cases you passed the exact same number of arguments, it just happens that you've split the function execution in two because of a poor language.

Comment: @lukas, in languages supporting such fancy constructs as arrays or (gasp!) lists, how about `Matrix.Create(input);` where `input` is, say, a .NET `IEnumerable<SomeAppropriateType>`? That way you also don't need a separate overload when you want to create a matrix holding 10 elements instead of 9.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I edited the example to clarify a bit my example. The main point is the parameter in the method, not in the constructor. When the constructor is far from the method becomes harder to understand what the method is processing when there aren't any parameters.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: or the new and shiny C++11 initialization lists! `Matrix m({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9});`. (bear with me, it's not often one can brag about a nice syntax in C++)

Comment: @alpha123 You're right. Zero is best than one, but you can't have this in all methods. In my personal opinion, one is better than zero.

Comment: @lukas Some would say a `Matrix.Create(rows, columns)` that gives a zero or identity matrix would be better. You can then `matrix.Set(row, column, value)`. More important than avoiding 9 parameters is the fact that you have the flexibility to create matrices with dimensions other than 3x3.

Comment: @Cableb of course there are many possible solutions. But the problem is that 4x4 Matrices are widely used in computational intensive tasks e.g. games and for performance reason there are interfaces like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.matrix.aspx, hence the statement "four or more, never!" is BS

Comment: Also, as far I remember,"Clean Code" has also one another false statement "Every class should have maximum of 7 public methods" which is yet another BS.

Comment: @lukas Clean Code makes it clear in beginning of the book that the entire book is a point of view of experienced developers and not "The Ultimate Truth".

Comment: I agree. 3 is maximum. If you need more then create a data structure. However, this is a general rule. There may be rare cases where it makes sense. Clean Code is a wonderful resource.

Comment: By the way, Clean Code suggests that a good reasons this guideline is that it becomes exponentially more difficult to properly test the function with each new parameter.

Comment: @BSeven It's not a matter of testing; if you bundle up the arguments into some data structure, you're still passing the same amount of data. It's more a matter of memory - the number of ways you can permute `n` arguments is `n!` (which is way worse than `n^2` or `n^3`). The number of permutations for 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 arguments is 1, 2, 6, 24, and 120 respectively. This, of course, assumes that all permutations are equally likely. When you're creating vectors or matrixes, there's usually an implied order that's independent of the dimensions.

Comment: @alpha123 Presumably the zero argument method is intended to be used in the context of a class instance, in which case it gets its state from the class properties.  Assuming you write small classes with relatively little state that should be manageable.  Clean Code was written largely by Java programmers and most of the examples therein are in Java (and also encourages numerous small classes as preferable to a few large classes).

Comment: Zero arguments as "ideal" is a crock and one reason i think Clean Code is way overrated.

Comment: @PeterC The function can get information form the class itself. For example, myClass.toString(), List(1,2,3,4).avg(), List(null).isEmpty, List(1,4,3).len

Comment: You will have zero arguments in your methods when construct objects of classes with data, and then call a method in it to operate on that data. Utility method are opposite to that, where data flows and utility class methods only have logic. Though having zero arguments is good when it can be done, but there will be cases we don't want to do that (e.g. while using singleton pattern or creating utility classes)

Comment: I do not understand why people get so frustrated on `Zero arguments as "ideal"`. Apparently they didn't read the book or simple misunderstood what author had in mind. They forgot that this book is focus on coding in OO langues or  took this sentence literally. It doesn't mean `all function must zero arguments`! It means that if you can provide method with zero argument (in fact there is implicit `this` argument) you should do it. There are some screen cast with Uncle Bob where he show how it works then you can see it has a seance.

Comment: 0 arguments means no value has been injected to the function, so it is very coupled to whatever module surrounds it, what makes unit testing harder and dirty. That's not a good practice at all, I wouldn't recommend any book that encourages to treat SW as a craft. The goal is the opposite.

Comment: Perhaps the author meant that functions that DOESN'T need any parameters, are inherently simpler than those who need one..

Comment: @MarekR Because it's a stupid guideline. That advice pushes people to create a class with lots of public setters, set those things to what it needs to do, and then call an "ideal" zero-parameter "doStuff" method that has exactly the same complexity but adheres to this guideline.  A function should have as many parameters as it needs - zero isn't any better than two or three or 200, as long as the function actually needs those.

Comment: @MarekR You can write any software without using a single parameter-enabled method by wrapping it in classes that provide the execution context for it. However, that's just unecessary complexity in 99% of the cases. It makes understanding the software WAY harder than it needs to be, and it obfuscates what is actually needed for a method to run. No-no-no - that advice is dangerous BS, that's what it is.

Comment: It's a bullshit affirmation. Removing arguments from a method (to met the "ideal") usually implies adding instance variables or even worse, global ones. And the end result is far worse.

Answer (score 32):

If the domain classes in the application are designed correctly, the number of parameters that we pass into a function will be automatically reduced - because the classes know how to do their job and they have enough data to do their work.

For example, say you have a manager class which asks a 3rd grade class to complete the assignments.

If you model correctly,

```
3rdGradeClass.finishHomework(int lessonId) {
    result = students.assignHomework(lessonId, dueDate);
    teacher.verifyHomeWork(result);
}
```

This is simple.

If you don't have the correct model, the method will be like this

```
Manager.finishHomework(grade, students, lessonId, teacher, ...) {
    // This is not good.
}
```

The correct model always reduces the function parameters between the method calls as the correct functions are delegated to their own classes (Single responsibility) and they have enough data to do their work.

***Whenever I see the number of parameters increasing, I check my model to see if I designed my application model correctly.***

There are some exceptions though: When I need to create a transfer object or config objects, I will use a builder pattern to produce small built objects first before constructing a big config object.

Comment: In the example you need to pas students,teacher,dueDate as argument to first function only then this will work 3rdGradeClass.finishHomework(int lessonId,students,teacher,dueDate){} only then your correct example will work that incase is passing more arguments

Answer (score 18):

One aspect that the other answers do not take up is performance.

If you are programming in a sufficiently low level language (C, C++, assembly) a large number of parameters can be quite detrimental to performance on some architectures, especially if the function is called a large amount of times.

When a function call is made in ARM for instance, the first four arguments are placed in registers `r0` to `r3` and remaining arguments have to be pushed onto the stack. Keeping the number of arguments below five can make quite a difference for critical functions.

For functions that are called extremely often, even the fact that the program has to set up the arguments before each call can affect performance (`r0` to `r3` may be overwritten by the called function and will have to be replaced before the next call) so in that regard zero arguments are best.

**Update:**

KjMag brings up the interesting topic of inlining. Inlining will in some ways mitigate this since it will allow the compiler to perform the same optimizations that you would be able to do if writing in pure assembly. In other words, the compiler can see which parameters and variables are used by the called function and can optimize register usage so that stack read/write is minimized.

There are some problems with inlining though.

1. Inlining causes the compiled binary to grow since the same code is duplicated in binary form if it is called from multiple places. This is detrimental when it comes to I-cache usage.
2. Compilers usually only allow inlining up to a certain level (3 steps IIRC?). Imagine calling an inlined function from an inlined function from an inlined function. Binary growth would explode if `inline` was treated as mandatory in all cases.
3. There are plenty of compilers that will either completely ignore `inline` or actually give you errors when they encounter it.

Comment: Whether passing a large number of parameters is good or bad from a performance perspective depends upon the alternatives.  If a method needs a dozen pieces of information, and one will be calling it hundreds of times with the same values for eleven of them, having the method take an array could be faster than having it take a dozen parameters.  On the other hand, if every call will need a unique set of twelve values, creating and populating the array for each call could easily be slower than simply passing the values directly.

Comment: Doesn't inlining solve this problem?

Comment: @KjMag: Yes, to a certain degree. But there are a lot of gotchas depending on the compiler. Functions will usually only be inlined up to a certain level (if you call an inlined function that calls an inlined function that calls an inlined function....). If the function is large and is called from a lot of places, inlining everywhere makes the binary larger which may mean more misses in the I-cache. So inlining can help, but it's no silver bullet. (Not to mention there are quite a few old embedded compilers that don't support `inline`.)

Answer (score 11):

When the parameter list grows to more than five, consider defining a "context" structure or object.

This is basically just a structure that holds all the optional parameters with some sensible defaults set.

In the C procedural world a plain structure would do. In Java, C++ a simple object will suffice. Don't mess with getters or setters because the sole purpose of the object is to hold "public"ly settable values.

Comment: I agree, a context object can turn out to be very handy when function parameter structures start becoming rather complex. I had recently blogged about using [context objects with a visitor-like pattern](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/04/10/the-visitor-pattern-re-visited/)

Answer (score 5):

**No, there is no standard guideline**

But there are some techniques that can make a function with a lot of parameters more bearable.

**You could use a list-if-args parameter (args*) or a dictionary-of-args parameter (kwargs`**`)**

For instance, in python:

```
// Example definition
def example_function(normalParam, args*, kwargs**):
  for i in args:
    print 'args' + i + ': ' + args[i] 
  for key in kwargs:
    print 'keyword: %s: %s' % (key, kwargs[key])
  somevar = kwargs.get('somevar','found')
  missingvar = kwargs.get('somevar','missing')
  print somevar
  print missingvar

// Example usage

    example_function('normal parameter', 'args1', args2, 
                      somevar='value', missingvar='novalue')
```

Outputs:

```
args1
args2
somevar:value
someothervar:novalue
value
missing
```

**Or you could use object literal definition syntax**

For example, here's a JavaScript jQuery call to launch an AJAX GET request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://someurl.com/feed',
  data: data,
  success: success(),
  error: error(),
  complete: complete(),
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

If you take a look at jQuery's ajax class there are a *lot* (approximately 30) more properties that can be set; mostly because ajax communications are very complex. Fortunately, the object literal syntax makes life easy.

---

C# intellisense provides active documentation of parameters so it's not uncommon to see very complex arrangements of overloaded methods.

Dynamically typed languages like python/javascript have no such capability, so it's a lot more common to see keyword arguments and object literal definitions.

I prefer object literal definitions ([even in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx)) for managing complex methods because you can explicitly see which properties are being set when an object is instantiated. You'll have to do a little more work to handle default arguments but in the long run your code will be a lot more readable. With object literal definitions you can break your dependence on documentation to understand what your code is doing at first glance.

IMHO, overloaded methods are highly overrated.

*Note: If I remember right readonly access control should work for object literal constructors in C#. They essentially work the same as setting properties in the constructor.*

---

If you have never written any non-trivial code in a dynamically typed (python) and/or functional/prototype javaScript based language, I highly suggest trying it out. It can be an enlightening experience.

It's can be scary first to break your reliance on parameters for the end-all, be-all approach to function/method initialization but you will learn to do so much more with your code without having to add unnecessary complexity.

**Update:**

**I probably should have provided examples to demonstrate use in a statically typed language but I'm not currently thinking in a statically typed context. Basically, I've been doing too much work in a dynamically typed context to suddenly switch back.**

**What I *do* know is object literal definition syntax is completely possible in statically typed languages (at least in C# and Java) because I have used them before. In statically typed languages they're called 'Object Initializers'. Here are some links to show their use in [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108531/is-there-an-object-initializers-in-java) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).**

Comment: I'm not sure I like this method, mainly because you lose the self documenting value of individual parameters. For lists of like items this makes perfect sense (for instance a method that takes a list of strings and concatenates them) but for an arbitrary parameter set this is worse than the long method call.

Comment: @MichaelK Take another look at object initializers. They allow you to explicitly define properties as opposed to how they're implicitly defined in traditional method/function parameters. Read this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx, to see what I mean.

Comment: Creating a new type just to handle the parameter list sounds exactly like the definition of unnecessary complexity...  Sure, dynamic languages let you avoid that but then you get a single ball of goo parameter. Regardless, this doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @Telastyn What are you talking about? No new type was created, you declare properties directly using object literal syntax. It's like defining an anonymous object but the method interprets it as a key=value parameter grouping. What you're looking at is a method instantiation (not a parameter encapsulating object). If your beef is with parameter packaging, take a look at the Parameter Object pattern mentioned in one of the other questions because that's exactly what it is.

Comment: @EvanPlaice - Except that static programming languages by-and-large require a (often new) declared type in order to allow the Parameter Object pattern.

Comment: @Telastyn I'm not using the Parameter Object pattern. No new type is necessary. The object literal notation **is** the parameter declaration, it's just done in a key-value form as opposed to a list of values form. .axax() is nothing but a method with a **ton** of possible properties. Of course, it's subclassed in many ways to provide simpler forms too but it doesn't **have** to be. It's easy to manage complex combinations of parameter declarations without adding complexity once you learn to implement object literal declarations.

Comment: ...which are only really available in dynamic languages.

Comment: @Telastyn "...which are only really available in dynamic languages." Which is completely false. In C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx and in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108531/is-there-an-object-initializers-in-java.

Comment: @EvanPlaice This isn't the place for discussion. In C# you can use named parameters, but that's not the same as your object literal declarations. You can use object literal declarations in C# and Java, but that type is either anonymous (and thus isn't usable in the function since it can't meaningfully subtype any function parameter but 'object') *or* you're defining a new type, which brings us back to my original comment.

Comment: @Telastyn I give up, it's obviously don't understand what 'object initializers' are and I can't compare and contrast against the usefulness of an approach that you are't aware of.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3150/discussion-between-telastyn-and-evan-plaice)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, more than 2 is where my code smell alarm triggers. When you consider functions to be **operations** (that is, a translation from input to output), it is uncommon that more than 2 parameters are used in an operation. *Procedures* (that is a series of steps to achieve a goal) will take more inputs and are sometimes the best approach, but in most languages these days should not be the norm.

But again, that's the guideline rather than a rule. I often have functions that take more than two parameters due to unusual circumstances or ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

Very much like Evan Plaice is saying, I'm a huge fan of simply passing associative arrays (or your language's comparable data structure) into functions whenever possible.

Thus, instead of (for example) this:

```
<?php

createBlogPost('the title', 'the summary', 'the author', 'the date of publication, 'the keywords', 'the category', 'etc');

?>
```

Go for:

```
<?php

// create a hash of post data
$post_data = array(
  'title'    => 'the title',
  'summary'  => 'the summary',
  'author'   => 'the author',
  'pubdate'  => 'the publication date',
  'keywords' => 'the keywords',
  'category' => 'the category',
  'etc'      => 'etc',
);

// and pass it to the appropriate function
createBlogPost($post_data);

?>
```

Wordpress does a lot of stuff this way, and I think it works well. (Though my example code above is imaginary, and is not itself an example from Wordpress.)

This technique allows you to pass a lot of data into your functions easily, yet frees you from having to remember the order in which each must be passed.

You'll also appreciate this technique when comes time to refactor - instead of having to potentially change the order of a function's arguments (such as when you realize you need to pass Yet Another Argument), you don't need to change your functions's parameter list at all.

Not only does this spare you from having to re-write your function definition - it spares you from having to change the order of arguments each time the function is invoked. That's a huge win.

Comment: Seeing this posted highlights another benefit of the pass-a-hash approach: notice that my first code example is so long it generates a scrollbar, while the second fits cleanly on the page. The same will likely be true in your code editor.

Answer (score 0):

A previous [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145055/are-there-guidelines-on-how-many-parameters-a-function-should-accept/145073#145073) mentioned a reliable author who stated that the less parameters your functions have, the better you are doing. The answer did not explain why but the books explains it, and here are two of the most convincing reasons as why you need to adopt this philosophy and with which I personally agree with:

- Parameters belong to a level of abstraction which is different from that of the function. This means the reader of your code will have to think about the nature and the purpose of the parameters of your functions: this thinking is "lower level" than that of the name and the purpose of their corresponding functions.
- The second reason to have as less parameters as possible to a function is testing: for example, if you have a function with 10 parameters, think about how many combinations of parameters you have to cover all the test cases for, for instance, a unit test. Less parameters = less tests.

Answer (score 0):

To provide some more context around the advice for the ideal number of function arguments being zero in Robert Martin's "Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship", the author says the following as one of his points:

> Arguments are hard. They take a lot of conceptual power. That's why I
>   got rid of almost all of them from the example. Consider, for
>   instance, the `StringBuffer` in the example. We could have passed it
>   around as an argument rather than making it an instance variable, but
>   then our readers would have had to interpret it each time they saw it.
>   When you are reading the story told by the module, `includeSetupPage()`
>   is easier to understand than `includeSetupPageInto(newPageContent)`. The
>   argument is at a different level of abstraction that the function name
>   and forces you to know a detail (in other words, `StringBuffer`) that
>   isn't particularly important at that point.

For his `includeSetupPage()` example above, here's a small snippet of his refactored "clean code" at the end of the chapter:

```java
// *** NOTE: Commments are mine, not the author's ***
//
// Java example
public class SetupTeardownIncluder {
    private StringBuffer newPageContent;

    // [...] (skipped over 4 other instance variables and many very small functions)

    // this is the zero-argument function in the example,
    // which calls a method that eventually uses the StringBuffer instance variable
    private void includeSetupPage() throws Exception {
        include("SetUp", "-setup");
    }

    private void include(String pageName, String arg) throws Exception {
        WikiPage inheritedPage = findInheritedPage(pageName);
        if (inheritedPage != null) {
            String pagePathName = getPathNameForPage(inheritedPage);
            buildIncludeDirective(pagePathName, arg);
        }
    }

    private void buildIncludeDirective(String pagePathName, String arg) {
        newPageContent
            .append("\n!include ")
            .append(arg)
            .append(" .")
            .append(pagePathName)
            .append("\n");
    }
}
```

The author's "school of thought" argues for small classes, low (ideally 0) number of function arguments, and very small functions. While I also don't fully agree with him, I found it thought-provoking and I feel that the idea of zero function arguments as an ideal can be worth considering. Also, note that even his small code snippet above has non-zero argument functions as well, so I think it depends on the context.

(And as others have pointed out, he also argues that more arguments make it harder from a testing point of view. But here I mainly wanted to highlight the above example and his rationale for zero function arguments.)

Answer (score -1):

Ideally zero.  One or two are ok, three in certain cases.
Four or more is usually a bad practice.

As well as the single responibility principles that others have noted you can also think of it from testing and debugging perspectives.

If there is one parameter, knowing it's values, testing them and finding error with them is 'relatively easy as there is only one factor.  As you increase the factors, the total complexity increases rapidly.  For an abstract example:

Consider a 'what to wear in this weather' program.
Consider what it could do with one input - temperature.  As you can imagine, the results of what to wear are pretty simple based on that one factor.  Now consider what the program might/could/should do if it is actually passed temperature, humidity, dewpoint, precipitation, etc.  Now imagine how hard it would to debug if it gave the 'wrong' answer to something.

Comment: If a function has zero parameters, it's either returning a constant value (useful in some circumstances, but rather limiting) or it is using some concealed state that would be better off made explicit. (In OO method calls, the context object is sufficiently explicit that it doesn't cause problems.)

Comment: -1 for not quoting the source

Comment: Are you seriously saying that ideally all functions would take no parameters?   Or is this hyperbole?

Comment: See Uncle Bob's argument at: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1375308 and note that at the bottom he says "Functions should have a small number of arguments. No argument is best, followed by one, two, and three. More than three is very questionable and should be avoided with prejudice."

Comment: I have given the source.  Funny no comments since then.  I have also tried to answer the 'guideline' part as many now consider Uncle Bob and Clean Code to be guidelines.  Interesting that the hugely upvote top answer (currently) says not aware of any guideline.  Uncle Bob did not _intend_ to be authorative but it somewhat is and this answer at least tries to be an answer to the specifics of the question.